# Why do successive redshifts multiply rather than add?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, redshift

I understand the argument presented in the answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156517/proof-of-expression-to-combine-different-redshifts) on how successive redshifts combine, such that $$1+z = (1+z_1)(1+z_2) = 1 + z_1 + z_2 + z_1z_2 \\ \therefore z = z_1 + z_2 + z_1z_2.$$However, this seems to contradict the intuition that (non-relativistically) the velocities $v = zc$ giving rise to the redshifts should just add. Say for example that I measure the redshift of light coming from a torch on a train. The train is moving away from me at $v_1 = z_1c$ and the person holding the torch is moving away from me at $v_2 = z_2c$ relative to the train. The total velocity of the torch relative to me is then $v = v_1 + v_2 = (z_1+z_2)c$, but the original formula above suggests that the total redshift is not $z_1+z_2$ but $z_1+z_2+z_1z_2$. How is this conflict resolved? Is it because this is the non-relativistic limit, and so $z_1z_2$ would be small?

Answer (score 1):

As you suggest, the resolution is indeed that both $v=zc$ and $v=v_1+v_2$ correspond to the nonrelativistic limit.

For relativistic speeds, the appropriate expressions are
$$1+z=\sqrt{\frac{1+v/c}{1-v/c}}$$
and
$$v=\frac{v_1+v_2}{1+v_1v_2/c^2}.$$
By substituting the second equation into the first, you can verify that
$$1+z=\sqrt{\frac{1+v_1/c}{1-v_1/c}}\sqrt{\frac{1+v_2/c}{1-v_2/c}}=(1+z_1)(1+z_2).$$